# How to use a symbol as input for a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to create a function that creates a rectangle made of an inputted character. So,

```
def Make_character_rectangle(height, width, char):

char = str(char)
while height > 0:
    height = height-1
    print(t * width)
```

So Make _character_rectangle(3, 2, %) should make:

%%

%%

%%

however when i input a symbol such as % into the function, it says invalid syntax. I tried converting char into a string but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Why not pass a *string* into the function? "Symbols" are not a Python construct, just pass `'%'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Make_character_rectangle(height, width, char):

    char = str(char)
    while height > 0:
        height = height-1
        print(char * width)
```

Not sure what 't' was, but the above function now produces

```
>>> Make_character_rectangle(2,3,'%')
%%%
%%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you defined t in print(t * width). Change the t to char.

You can also change height = height - 1 to height -= 1.